# Stuck With Oracle SQL SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL syntax like this :

```
SELECT
P.FORM_NO,
SUM(Q.QTY) as QTY,
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(P.DATE_ADDED,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MONTH')

FROM
SEIAPPS_PRODUCTION_STATUS P,
SEIAPPS_QTY Q

WHERE Q.STATUS_QTY='OK'
GROUP BY P.FORM_NO
```

But now I facing problem with that syntax that give error :

```
Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression in...
```

I see the problem is when I want to add more column in that syntax.

Anyone please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(P.DATE_ADDED,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MONTH')` is not an aggregate, so you will need to `GROUP BY` this (`P.DATE_ADDED`) as well.

Comment: OK now I tried to clear that, but why when I try to add another column, it still error like I said?

Comment: For each non-aggregate functions, you need to add the column in the `group by` clause also.